# Iphone sdk : Where to put code for a grouped table

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a root view controller with no nib file,

I tried adding this at cellForRowAtIndexPath as that passes in a UITableView as tableView.

So I put :

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

It ran with no error but it didnt seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippit won't change anything, because the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is only called when an *existing* table view needs to know how to draw its content. No existing table view, no getting called.

Remove that line from your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and define a `UITableView` object either:

- In the XIB file (this is the easiest approach)
- In the initialisation code for your view controller

As @FenchKiss Dev wrote, if you set up the table in code you need to add it as a subview to an existing view, for it to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the tableView to your view ?

```
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```